# The arrow in my figure is not appearing correctly. What is the mistake?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I am trying to compile the following code to get a standalone pdf output to use it in another document.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
\draw [dashed] (-2.1,0) circle [radius=1cm] ;
\draw [<-,thick] (-2.1,-1.4)--(0,-1.4) ;
\draw (-1,-1.2) node {$x_2$} ;
\draw (3,0) circle [radius = 0.7cm];
\draw [dashed](4.5,0)  circle [radius = 0.7cm];
\draw [->,thick] (3,-1.1) -- (4.5,-1.1);
\draw (3.75,-0.9) node {$x_2$};
\draw [dashed] (-2.1,0) -- (0,0);
\draw [dashed] (3,0) -- (4.5,0);
\draw  (0,0) -- (3,0) ;
\draw (0,-0.25) node {$-$} ;
\draw (-2.1,-0.25) node {$-$} ;
\draw (3,-0.25) node {$+$} ;
\draw (4.5,-0.25) node {$+$} ;
\draw (-1,1.2) node {$-q$} ;
\draw (3.75,1) node {$+q$} ;
\draw [->,ultra thick] (-2.1,1.75) -- (4.5,1.75) ;
\draw (4.7,1.75) node {E};
\draw (1.25,2) node {$\mu_i = q(x_1 + x_2)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this, I get the following output:
[image: Error Image with arrow half outside the bottom of the document]

The arrow under x2 is only half visible. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Switch to the newer TikZ library `arrows.meta`. Then the bounding box calculation includes the arrow head:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
\draw [dashed] (-2.1,0) circle [radius=1cm] ;
\draw [<-,thick] (-2.1,-1.4)--(0,-1.4) ;
\draw (-1,-1.2) node {$x_2$} ;
\draw (3,0) circle [radius = 0.7cm];
\draw [dashed](4.5,0)  circle [radius = 0.7cm];
\draw [->,thick] (3,-1.1) -- (4.5,-1.1);
\draw (3.75,-0.9) node {$x_2$};
\draw [dashed] (-2.1,0) -- (0,0);
\draw [dashed] (3,0) -- (4.5,0);
\draw  (0,0) -- (3,0) ;
\draw (0,-0.25) node {$-$} ;
\draw (-2.1,-0.25) node {$-$} ;
\draw (3,-0.25) node {$+$} ;
\draw (4.5,-0.25) node {$+$} ;
\draw (-1,1.2) node {$-q$} ;
\draw (3.75,1) node {$+q$} ;
\draw [->,ultra thick] (-2.1,1.75) -- (4.5,1.75) ;
\draw (4.7,1.75) node {E};
\draw (1.25,2) node {$\mu_i = q(x_1 + x_2)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

You can do two things (apart from loading the TikZ library for arrows).  You can add a border to the `standalone` by passing it through the `\documentclass[border=10pt]...` or you can enlarge the bounding box for the figure by adding something like

```
\path (current bounding box.south) -- ++ (0,-10pt);
```

as the last line in the environment.

**Additional comments**

You've hardwired everything very tightly which will make it a bit of a nightmare to tweak later on, should you want to do so.  In the code below, I've rewritten your diagram using only four explicitly defined coordinates, everything else is identified relative to those coordinates.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (-2.1,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (3,0);
  \coordinate (D) at (4.5,0);

  \draw          (B) circle [radius=1cm];
  \draw [dashed] (A) circle [radius=1cm] ;
  \draw          (C) circle [radius = 0.7cm];
  \draw [dashed] (D) circle [radius = 0.7cm];

  \draw [<-,thick] 
    ([yshift=-1.4cm]A) -- ([yshift=-1.4cm]B) 
    node[midway,above] {$x_2$};

  \draw [->,thick] 
    ([yshift=-1.1cm]C) -- ([yshift=-1.1cm]D) 
    node[midway,above] {$x_2$};

  \draw [dashed] 
    (A) -- (B) 
    node[midway,yshift=1.2cm] {$-q$}
    node[pos=0,below] {$-$};

  \draw [dashed] 
    (C) -- (D) 
    node[midway,yshift=1cm] {$+q$}
    node[pos=1,below] {$+$};

  \draw  
    (B) -- (C) 
    node[pos=0,below] {$-$} 
    node[pos=1,below] {$+$};

  \draw [->,ultra thick] 
    ([yshift=1.75cm]A) -- ([yshift=1.75cm]D)
    node[midway,above,inner sep=0pt] {$\mu_i = q(x_1 + x_2)$}
    node[pos=1,right] {E};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]